# Collision of a line and object ( Corona SDK )

Tags: object, line, coronasdk, collision

I am developing a game when there is a line and physics object

The line code is:

And the interesting thing is that when i code print ("collision is here") (for ex) they some how don't even collide!

Both line and obj bodies are static

How can make this collision happed? thanks in advance!

Comment: horrible copy and paste.. please make your code neater above

Answer (score 0):

Static bodies can't collide with each other, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7697555/1369488) question has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

IF both lines are static make a function where you detect the x and y of both object and make equation accordingly, for example :  line.x + 20 > obj.x then print(collide).